# Play Framework Serial Tuple3

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I am experimenting around with Scala and Play. I want to return a Tuple, in this case a Tuple3 but could be Tuple of any size. I want to serialize the Tuple as JSON, but Play doesn't seem to know how to serialize a Tuple.

I'm just trying to do something very simple like the following

```
def getClient(clientId: Int) = Action {
    val result = ("I", "AM", "TUPLE")
    Ok(Json.toJson(result))
}
```

No Json serializer found for type (String, String, String). Try to implement an implicit Writes or Format for this type.

I tried something like this but it only seems to work on Tuple2.

```
val seq = Seq[(String,String)](("attr1"->"val1"),("attr2"->"val2"))


val s = Json.toJson(seq.map(e => Json.obj((e._1 -> e._2))))
 Ok(s).as(JSON)
```

Comment: Why do you want to rendre a Tuple3 as Json? How do you want your Json to look like? If you know this you can write your own implicit writer. But is there a reason you don't want to use a case class?

Comment: What if my service class method returns Tuple (Client, Seq[Project]), I would want to serialize that as Json to return to client. In Java I would just wrap them into a DTO object. Wondering if maybe need to do same thing in Scala.

Comment: Okay.. but what JSON are you expecting, exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a case class like this.

```
case class MyCaseClass(string1: String, string2: String, string3: String)
```

then you  have to add an implicit writer with

```
implicit val myCaseClassFormat = Json.format[MyCaseClass]
```

then you can do `Json.toJson(MyCaseClass("I", "AM", "TUPLE"))`

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, same approach I take with Java